# How to get the true PID of portable TOR browser?

Tags: bash, pid, tor

Getting and use the true PID of a installed programm like xed or Firefox are working fine p.e. on follow way:

```
#!/bin/bash

xed & PID=$! # Start xed and get PID for later
echo "$PID"

Running the xed some time

kill -15 "$PID" # Soft Kill of xed
```

Getting the PID of portable TOR browser give back a PID which looks like are not from TOR browser (possible from one of a TOR helper scripts inside the portable Tor browser folder)

The result of this is. The Tor browser cant be closed on follow way by the wrong TOR PID:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/username/desktop/Tor_FF/start-tor-browser.desktop & PID=$! # Start xed and get PID for later
echo "$PID"

Running the xed some time

kill -15 "$PID" # Soft Kill of xed
```

Envirement:

- Linux like Ubuntu 64, 20.x, Gnome

Comment: Try `pgrep <name of the tor process>`. For the name, check the content of the .desktop file or look at `top`/`pstree` once TOR is running.

Comment: @Socowi, getting the true PID by hand by pstree and top are working. The processname of TOR browser is firefox.real. pidof -x firefox.real are giving me 4 different PIDs. The PID from TOR browser which works for me are the 4th of this 4 PIDs.

Comment: I guess either `pgrep -o firefox.real` or `-n` should do the trick then.

Comment: @Socowi, now I tested it. It works great on follow way for me: PID=$(pgrep -o firefox.real); echo "$PID" Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on input from Socowi, follow solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOR_PID=$(pgrep -o firefox.real); echo "$TOR_PID"

# running TOR a little bit

kill -15 "$TOR_PID" # Soft Kill of xed
```

## Some remarks:

Check onetime by hand what the name of the Tor process is by:

- start the mobile version of TOR
- pstree and top

Get the PID by processname:

```
TOR_PID=$(pgrep -o firefox.real); echo "$TOR_PID"
```

Doublecheck by the follow the PID are realy the right one from TOR:

- check by pstree and top

Check the PID by follow:

```
kill -15 "$TOR_PID" # Soft Kill of TOR browser
```